# Thymeleaf var as value of attribute

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

```
$("#comparison-qty").html('<div id="comparison-qty"><a href="'+
    [[${url_compare_view}]] +'">' + error.transport + '</a></div>');
```

Hello, I have this code. I want `[[${url_compare_view}]]` this thymeleaf var to be value of attribute href, but it isn't work. Where wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to store your variable on `inline` script, in order to access its data later, because thymeleaf only works in `html` page not on `js` files. Try this.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var urlCompareView = /*[[${url_compare_view}]]*/ 'url_compare_view';
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Then you can use ir on your javascripts.

```
$("#comparison-qty").html('<div id="comparison-qty"><a href="'+ url_compare_view +'">' + error.transport + '</a></div>');
```

Hope it helps you.

**Edit**

If you want do it all inlinie. try this.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var urlCompareView = /*[[${url_compare_view}]]*/ 'url_compare_view';
    $("#comparison-qty").html('<div id="comparison-qty"><a href="'+ url_compare_view +'">' + error.transport + '</a></div>');
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: I mean, I want to avoid using var urlCompareView.

Comment: Ok, replace variable by `[[${url_compare_view}]]` inside string content.